# getting this error Failed to take /etc/passwd lock: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**when i tried to use command**-  `sudo apt install libudev-dev`it give me this error

```
Failed to take /etc/passwd lock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

what to do pls tell me

Comment: is that exactly the output, nothing at all more than that? try `sudo apt update`

Comment: What distribution and release are you running?  Clearly it's Debian-based, but is it Ubuntu?  20.04, 22.04, an interim release?  Also, is Systemd running?

Comment: Since I just got this exact error while trying to upgrade my WSL Kali, my guess is that.

Comment: @Panki - There is no guarantee you actually have the same problem as the author.  Best to allow the author to clarify their question by editing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across this thing that i tried and it worked! Might work for you aswell here: https://databasefaqs.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info_silent

sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/* /var/lib/dpkg/info_silent

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info_silent /var/lib/dpkg/info

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Done!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! As a heads-up, I know this is a bit tricky to navigate - You properly edited your other answer that a Mod deleted.  But rather than posting a new one, you really should have Flagged it for the Moderator to undelete.

Answer (score 2):

Landed here looking for a WSL-specific problem.  I found some other people's solutions here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10397

The gist of it is:

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd-timesyncd.postinst /tmp/
$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.postinst /tmp/
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

That should allow dpkg to finish "configuring" systemd (because we removed the problematic scripts)

After that you can put the scripts back and continue apt upgrade

```
$ sudo mv /tmp/systemd-timesyncd.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/
$ sudo mv /tmp/systemd.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: For anyone else coming here, I've also seen errors on upgrades to the following packages on Debian sid: `udev`, `cron-daemon-common`, `cron`

Answer (score 2):

`systemd.postinsts` script calls `systemd-sysusers`, and it in turn tries to get a lock with fcntl F_OFD_SETLKW which fails.

strace output of `sudo systemd-sysusers`:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/.pwd.lock", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = 3
fcntl(3, F_OFD_SETLKW, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

WSL1 does not support these kinds of locks: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1927

That ticket is about F_SETLK but it's likely the same situation with F_OFD_SETLKW.

Although that ticket is closed it's labeled `fixed-in-wsl2` meaning there are no plans to fix it in WSL1.